# Getting value of the arraylist depending on the key value in HashMap

Tags: java

I have a Map declared as

```
    Map<Integer,List<String>> parameter_map=new LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
```

I want to fetch the value of the list depending on the key value.
How can I do this .Please help.

Thank you

Comment: -1 What have you tried and what tutorials/documentation did you read that failed to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
Integer value = new Integer(3);
List<String> aList = parameter_map.get(value);
```

Comment: I want to fetch the list depending on the key.How will this help me do  so?

Comment: Maps work as key-value pairs.  Whatever key you use would result in the appropriate value being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the map is containing the following values.

```
parameter_map.put(1, <first instance of arrayList>);
parameter_map.put(2, <second instance of arrayList>);
...
```

SO in order to get the value of value from the map, you need to use:

```
List<String> al = parameter_map.get(1);
```

In order to get the value from this array list, you need to iterate over it.

```
  for(String s: al)
  System.out.println(" list value " + s);
```

Hope this will help you.